# Assets refresh button spinning, not showing file locations

Tags: assets

I've just whipped up a new EE v2.5.5 site with a copy of Assets 2.0.2. I've added in a file upload location, and when I go to Assets I see a spinning refresh button with no locations showing below.

I noticed that if I click 'Update indexes', the location I added in shows up there OK.

Any ideas what might be behind this?

Answer (score 2):

You always need to start by updating your indexes. That’s Assets’ equivalent of EE’s upload directory synchronization. Without updating your indexes, the File Manager won’t know that your upload directories even exist.

The Refresh button in the File Manager is sortof a Poor Man’s Update Indexes – it will only update indexes for the currently-viewed folder’s files. But again, if you haven’t done the real Update Indexes yet, you won’t have a currently-viewed folder in the first place.

Comment: OK, well in this case I haven't actually clicked refresh. When I go to the Assets screen, it's just spinning around already!

If I go to the update indexes, I click the button which makes it fade out (which I assume means it's done?) but nothing changes on the Assets screen. Still spinny refresh!

Comment: Hi Brandon - I think i've solved this one. The server default is set to index.html, and I had an index.html file in the root (acting as a holding page). Without that, Assets works like a charm!

Answer (score 1):

> Hi Brandon - I think i've solved this one. The server default is set to index.html, and I had an index.html file in the root (acting as a holding page). Without that, Assets works like a charm!

With that in mind, the issue was simply that Assets’ Ajax requests were getting sent to your index.html file rather than index.php.

You can keep your index.html page in place and simply point Assets to your index.php file by adding this to your system/expressionengine/config/config.php file:

```
$config['assets_site_url'] = '/index.php';
```